# How to connect sql server to php

Tags: php, sql-server

Hi I had a question about connecting php to sql server I install odbc driver and confige php.ini file. But when execute I get error.
I change the computer but still get same error.

```
    <?php
$serverName = "YASSERAHMMED\YASOFT";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"ELECTERC_DB", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"google");
$con = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );
if( $con === false ) {
    //echo sqlsrv_errors();
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT_CUSTMERS";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $con, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      echo $row['date'].", ".$row['id']."<br />";
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
?>
```

the result is :
error 5701 and 5703

Comment: Please post your actual code to the question, not a picture..

Comment: There are a number of reasons why you should paste your code as text into your question instead of a screen shot. When attempting to help you fix your code, most people will want to copy your code to paste into their own development environment to play around with. Posting pictures of your code makes that impossible. The text in pictures can also not be searched in case someone else is looking for an answer to the same question. A third problem is that these pictures are so small that they are unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

I finally use PDO string connection to resolve the problem..
thanks every one...

```
$serverName = "YASSERAHMMED\YASOFT";  

try  
{  
  $conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$serverName ; Database=ELECTERC_DB", "", "");  
  $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); 
  if($conn){
     // echo'ggggg';
  } else{
      echo'undone';
  }
}  
catch(Exception $e)  
{   
  die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) );   
}
```